# Nodejs Readable Stream push usage

Tags: node.js, stream

I run some code in command with node;
It's on error when the code like this:

```
> var rs = new require('stream').Readable();
> rs.push("123");rs.push(null); // two pushes are in the same row;
```

but this is error:

```
> var rs = new require('stream').Readable();
> rs.push("123");  // I went them are not in the same row;
// then get a error, like :
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: not implemented
    at Readable._read (_stream_readable.js:446:22)
    at Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
    at maybeReadMore_ (_stream_readable.js:431:12)
    at _stream_readable.js:422:7
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

I need code like this:

```
var rs = new require('stream').Readable();
rs.pipe(someWriteAbleStream)
// some time later
rs.push(somedata);
// some time late
rs.push(somedata);
// ...
rs.push(null);
```

Thanks;

Comment: read the doc : http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable_1

Comment: thanks.I lost _read method

Comment: @user3305221 can you post that as an accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

because , if you no rs.push(null), then cache is null, so rs call ._read() to read.

if rs.push(null) , mean is done.